# Play Framework Image BLOB File for Test Object Yaml

Tags: java, mysql, blob, playframework, yaml

How do you set up a Test Blob Image using the yaml structure?

Also, what is the database structure for a BLOB file? (MySQL)

Comment: Do none of the answers work for you? For me this worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7415620/11236

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same kind of problem a while ago on a project. However as I could not find a way to solve this with the fixtures (as the database stores the blob object as a string as Pere explained above), I created a workaround to at least solve this problem in a test-case-scenario. I created the following file /app/job/Bootstrap.java:

```
import play.test.*;
import play.jobs.*;
import play.db.DB;
import models.*;

import java.util.List;

@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
     public void doJob() {
        // Load default data if the database is empty
        if(Item.count() == 0) {
            Fixtures.loadModels("my_fixtures.yml");
            List<Item> allItems = Item.findAll();
            for (Item a: allItems){
                DB.execute("UPDATE `Item` SET image='item_" + a.name.toLowerCase() + ".png|image/png' WHERE id=" + a.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing I do is filling the database with initial data if there are no 'Item' already stored in the database.
The second thing is iterating over all the 'Item' which play! just stored in the database, which are read from the "my_fixtures.yml" file. Here for each item the string field will get updated as shown in the example above.

I know this is not exactly the answer to question in the OP, but it gives some kind idea to work around this issue..

*EDIT: In the example given above I assume that the pictures are uploaded manually to your attachment folder as given in your **application.conf**, and that each image name is like: "item_<item_name_in_lowercase>" with a ".png" extension*

Comment: I'm still seeing empty values in the fields of the Blob, even after putting the image files in the data folder and executing the update code above.

Comment: Correction: when I tried, within the doJob() method, to read the images again, I didn't see any fields to the blob, so I assumed this didn't work. However, when I did the same in a Controller later, the image was correct, and I managed to render it correctly in a browser!

Answer (score 1):

Well, play is quite weird on that point.

The blob is **not saved** into the database but in a **upload folder** defined in your `application.conf`. It is the path toward the file that is saved in the database.

I cannot check it right now, but I seem to recall they are saved as textuel representations (VARCHAR, TEXT)

Answer (score 1):

The blob is saved in the file system, by default under "data/attachments" if I recall correctly, but you can change that in the configuration (`application.conf`)

In the database, it's stored as a String (varchar in most DB) with two components: the name and the mime type. It looks like:

```
12345asbcdefghi12345abcdfed|image/jpeg
```

The first part is the name of the file. When you upload a file Play generates a unique UUID as name to avoid collision. Yes, this means you are loosing the original name. (note: now I'm having doubts on the name part, I would swear it is lost, but I may be wrong!)

The second part (after the |) is the myme type. Play uses a magic-myme library to automatically detect it.

You can see the code [here](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/Blob.java).

Comment: So how would you map a image/BLOB in a yaml file:  
  
User(john):  
    name: "John Smith"  
    email: john@john.com  
    lang: es  
    image: filename|image/jpeg  
Thanks

Comment: Having a really bad time trying to get line breaks in comments, hope you can understand the syntax without the line breaks.

Comment: Well, to be honest I've never tried it, but knowing that it's stored as a varchar, adding the filname|myme-type should work.

Comment: And I confirm your point, Pere, the filename is lost. You have to mannualy save it. Lunatech has written a nice article about it : http://www.lunatech-research.com/playframework-file-upload-blob

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of Unji's answer that loads the images from a folder in conf, please note that I have removed all the import statements:

```
/**
 * A job executed when the application starts.
 */
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

  /**
   * Loads the initial data if there are no
   * WebAdministrators at the database.
   * <p>
   *   It loads images on the post with the following criteria:
   *   <ol>
   *     <li>file loaction: /conf/initialMedia/</li>
   *     <li>file name: {post.title.toCamelCase()}-{i}.jpg</li>
   *   </ol>
   *   Where i must start in 0.
   * </p>
   */
  @Override
  public void doJob() {
    // Check if the database is empty
    if(WebAdministrator.count() == 0) {
      Logger.info("Loading Initial Data.");
      Fixtures.loadModels("initial-data.yml");
      List<Post> posts = Post.findAll();
      for (Post post: posts) {
        Logger.info("Looking for files for post: [" + post.title + "]");
        for (int i=0; true; i++) {
          VirtualFile vf = VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/conf/initialMedia/"
              + JavaExtensions.camelCase(post.title) + "-" + i + ".jpg");
          File imageFile = vf.getRealFile();

          if (imageFile.exists()) {
            try {
              Blob blobImage = new Blob();
              blobImage.set(new FileInputStream(imageFile), MimeTypes.getContentType(imageFile.getName()));
              MediaItem mediaItem = new Image(blobImage);
              mediaItem.save();
              post.mediaItems.add(mediaItem);
              post.save();
              Logger.info("File: [%s] Loaded", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              // this should never happen.
            }
          } else {
            Logger.info("Media Loaded for post [%s]: %d files.", post.title, i);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```