# How to load picture in YAML file

Tags: playframework, yaml

How is it possible to load picture with YAML file?

With this model :

```
    @Entity 
    public class User extends Model { 
            public String name; 
            public Blob pict; 
    }
```

I tried :

```
    User (inconnu01): 
        name:            Inconnu01 
        pict:               335af415-26dc-45a7-8d5c-c146309b9958|image/jpeg
```

where "335af415-26dc-45a7-8d5c-c146309b9958" is the picture filename 
in data\attachments repository.

But this doesn't works.

Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it can, but take a look at the [Fixtures.java](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/test/Fixtures.java) source code.

Here's a similar question still unanswered [Play Framework Image BLOB File for Test Object Yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928776/play-framework-image-blob-file-for-test-object-yaml)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not find how to get there and Fixtures.java does not seem to afford it. When I will have time, I will try to make it evolve in this direction. This is for me a missing unit tests. Best regards, Chris